# Background image header not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have recently started web designing again and all good so far.
But now I have a little problem, for some reason the background image in the header will not show up whilst in the jumbotron it does.

I have searched on here for a solution and therefore tried,
deleting the height of the header, just using background: instead of background-image and switching the url html to a different picture and to a url in my directory with no succes.

```css
body, html {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 
 
}
p, h3 {
 color:#A9BF00;
}
.header {
 width:100%;
 background-image:url (http://static.sgv2.com/img/12011/aspect/700x500/content/1/1112081830261591-pearlz_chalk_board.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
}
.header img {
 position:relative;
 left:-100px;
}

.nav a { 
 color:#A9BF00;
}

.jumbotron {
 background-image: url(https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/v/t1.0-9/1901796_253871248070239_1337858622_n.png?oh=958dde5dfd4ff94046092785f3d8d0f7&oe=5686AEA0&__gda__=1455632370_852f1972f7da55909fbcb6b95cdcea63);
 background-size:cover;
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
}

.supporting {
 text-align:center;
}
.col-md-4 {
 margin-left:7%;
 height:200px;
 width:300px;
}

.col-md-4 img {
 height:200px;
 width:300px;
}

.footer {
 background-color:gray;
 position:relative;
 top:230px;
 height:50px;
}

.footer h5 {
 color:#A9BF00;
 margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>La Venezia</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Header Section-->
     <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
       <img src="lavenezia.png"/>
      </div>
     </div>
           <!--Nav Section-->
        <div class="navigation">
         <div class="container">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
           <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">Assortiment</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">Het Team</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div>
   </div>   
         <!--Big Picture Section-->
   <div class="jumbotron">
    
   </div>
      <!--Supporting Section-->
   <div class="supporting">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bliqx.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/girls-eating-burger.jpg"/>
      <h3>Eat</h3>
      <p>Bij ons kunt u terecht voor verse friet, snacks, broodjes en salades. Of u nou alleen, met z'n tweeën of met een groter gezelschap bij ons komt eten, wij zorgen er voor dat u goed verzorgd wordt. Lekker eten en drinken in een gezellige sfeer met een vriendelijke en enthiousiaste bediening.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive"
       src="http://worldsoccertalk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/soccer-on-tv.jpg"/>
      <h3>Relax</h3>
      <p>Wilt u tijdens het genot van u frietje even lekker rustig een wedstrijd bekijken van uw favoriete team? Dan kan dat! Met ons fox-sport pakket bent u altijd voorzien van de juiste kanalen.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive"
       src="http://cdn.listaka.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/03-friends-drinking-main.jpg"/>
      <h3>Enjoy</h3>
      <p>Omdat het leven te kort is om iets anders te zijn dan gelukkig</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
            <!--Footer Section-->
          <div class="footer">
           <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-2">
             <h5>La Venezia</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 text-right">
             <a href="#"><h5>Contact</h5></a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    background-image:url (http://static.sgv2.com/img/12011/aspect/700x500/content/1/1112081830261591-pearlz_chalk_board.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

to this:

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(http://static.sgv2.com/img/12011/aspect/700x500/content/1/1112081830261591-pearlz_chalk_board.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

There shouldn't be a space between url and (

Comment: aaah that was the problem! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://static.sgv2.com/img/12011/aspect/700x500/content/1/1112081830261591-pearlz_chalk_board.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You need to change the height as you wish